# T-SQL Pivot help required (I think)

Tags: t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I'm looking to get the values from 1 row in a table to be the column names in a query where the data for the columns comes from a second table. I think this can be achieved with a PIVOT but am getting nowhere in trying to work it out

Specifically we are looking to record the levels of Antibody for different Antigens over time for patients.
The actual Antigens that will be monitored will differ for each patient.
We therefore have a table that records the Antigens that will be monitored, this table is called reftblDSAColumnLabels. As you can see in the example there are two rows for different people, identified by the PersonCategoryId. This table has a unique constraint on the PersonCategoryId

*(The table actually has up to 'Antigen12Label' so that a maximum of 12 different Antigens can be monitored for Antibody levels per patient but I have simplified it here)*

[image: tblDSAColumnLabels]

The table that contains the data is called tblDSAData and you can see some representative rows below for the Patient with PersonCategoryId = 1
[image]

What I want to achieve is an output that has the following Column Headings where the PersonCategoryId  = 1

**PersonCategoryId   SampleDate   A1   Cw6   DR15   DR51**

and this where the PersonCategoryId = 2

**PersonCategoryId   SampleDate   A2   A3   B7   B9**

I feel that it should be fairly easy but I seem to have a mental block where PIVOT is concerned

Comment: Do you want this to be a dynamic solution?  Where you pass in the `personCategoryId` and the columns will change?

Comment: The query will be embedded in a Stored Proc with the PersonCategoryId passed in as a parameter.
I would always want to retrieve PersonCategoryId, SampleDate and then all the Antigen columns up to Antigen12Label & Antigen12Value.
If it is possible to restrict the Antigen columns returned to only those where Antigen(n)Label is not null that would be even better as there will never be data in the Antigen(n)Value column if the corresponding Label column is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well part of the problem that I see is you have two tables that are de-normalized, meaning you basically have two tables that are designed as spreadsheets and not tables. The best solution to this problem would be to restructure your tables.

If possible, my advice would be to change the table structure to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE reftblDSAColumnLabels
(
  [PersonCategoryId] int, 
  [AntigenNum] int, 
  [AntigenValue] varchar(4)
);

CREATE TABLE tblDSAData 
(
  [PersonCategoryId] int, 
  [SampleDate] datetime,
  [AntigenNum] int, 
  [AntigenValue] int
);
```

This way you could join the tables on both the `personCategoryId` and the `AntigenNum` (1, 2, 3, etc). You will see why I suggest this in a minute.

Since your tables are de-normalized it will be very difficult to generate the result set on the fly by passing in a `personCategoryId`. You will need to use dynamic SQL to generate the result based on the id that is submitted to a procedure.

In order to get this result, I would suggest apply both the UNPIVOT and PIVOT functions. The UNPIVOT is going to take your tables that are in multiple columns and convert them into the structures that I suggested above.  This will make getting the result much easier.

**UNPIVOT:**

You need to unpivot both tables, the queries to unpivot will be similar to the following:

```
select personCategoryId, 
  replace(replace(col, 'Antigen', ''), 'Label', '') colNum,
  value l_value
from reftblDSAColumnLabels
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in ([Antigen1Label], [Antigen2Label], [Antigen3Label], [Antigen4Label])
) unpiv
where PersonCategoryId = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22501/12)

```
select personCategoryId,SampleDate,
  replace(replace(col, 'Antigen', ''), 'Value', '') colNum,
  value d_value
from tblDSAData
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in ([Antigen1Value], [Antigen2Value], [Antigen3 Value], [Antigen4Value])
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22501/13). If you run these queries you will notice that you get a result similar to this:

```
| PERSONCATEGORYID | COLNUM | L_VALUE |
---------------------------------------
|                1 |      1 |      A1 |
|                1 |      2 |     Cw6 |
|                1 |      3 |    DR15 |
|                1 |      4 |    DR51 |
```

and

```
| PERSONCATEGORYID |                      SAMPLEDATE | COLNUM | D_VALUE |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                1 | February, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |    1278 |
|                1 | February, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      2 |   11272 |
|                1 | February, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      3 |    6880 |
|                1 | February, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      4 |    7544 |
|                1 | February, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |    1711 |
|                1 | February, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      2 |    9681 |
|                1 | February, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      3 |    8437 |
|                1 | February, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      4 |    8967 |
```

**PIVOT**

Once this data is in this multiple row format, you can easily join the results on the `personCategoryId` and the `colNum` and apply the PIVOT function to get the final result.  The code with the join and the PIVOT will be:

```
select *
from
(
  select l.personCategoryId, l_value, d_value, SampleDate
  from
  (
    select personCategoryId, 
      replace(replace(col, 'Antigen', ''), 'Label', '') colNum,
      value l_value
    from reftblDSAColumnLabels
    unpivot
    (
      value
      for col in ([Antigen1Label], [Antigen2Label], [Antigen3Label], [Antigen4Label])
    ) unpiv
    where PersonCategoryId = 1
  ) l
  inner join
  (
    select personCategoryId,SampleDate,
      replace(replace(col, 'Antigen', ''), 'Value', '') colNum,
      value d_value
    from tblDSAData
    unpivot
    (
      value
      for col in ([Antigen1Value], [Antigen2Value], [Antigen3Value], [Antigen4Value])
    ) unpiv
  ) d
    on l.PersonCategoryId = d.PersonCategoryId
    and l.colNum = d.colNum
) src
pivot
(
  max(d_value)
  for l_value in (A1, Cw6, DR15, DR51)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78088/2).

Now for your current problem, you need to pass in the `personCategoryId` so the column headers will be changing for each id. Since the column headers will change you will need to use dynamic SQL to get the result.  You can easily convert the above code into dynamic SQL and the script will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @personCategoryId int = 1

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(value) 
                    from
                    (
                      select value
                      from reftblDSAColumnLabels
                      unpivot
                      (
                        value
                        for col in ([Antigen1Label], [Antigen2Label], [Antigen3Label], [Antigen4Label])
                      ) unpiv
                      where PersonCategoryId = @personCategoryId
                    ) d
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT personCategoryId, SampleDate,' + @cols + '  
             from
              (
                select l.personCategoryId, l_value, d_value, SampleDate
                from
                (
                  select personCategoryId, 
                    replace(replace(col, ''Antigen'', ''''), ''Label'', '''') colNum,
                    value l_value
                  from reftblDSAColumnLabels
                  unpivot
                  (
                    value
                    for col in ([Antigen1Label], [Antigen2Label], [Antigen3Label], [Antigen4Label])
                  ) unpiv
                  where PersonCategoryId = '+cast(@personCategoryId as varchar(10))+'
                ) l
                inner join
                (
                  select personCategoryId,SampleDate,
                    replace(replace(col, ''Antigen'', ''''), ''Value'', '''') colNum,
                    value d_value
                  from tblDSAData
                  unpivot
                  (
                    value
                    for col in ([Antigen1Value], [Antigen2Value], [Antigen3Value], [Antigen4Value])
                  ) unpiv
                ) d
                  on l.PersonCategoryId = d.PersonCategoryId
                  and l.colNum = d.colNum
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                max(d_value)
                for l_value in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78088/16). All versions will give a result:

```
| PERSONCATEGORYID | SAMPLEDATE |   A1 |   CW6 |  DR15 | DR51 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                1 | 2013-02-08 | 1278 | 11272 |  6880 | 7544 |
|                1 | 2013-02-11 | 1711 |  9681 |  8437 | 8967 |
|                1 | 2013-02-13 | 2107 | 11516 |  8958 | 7884 |
|                1 | 2013-02-15 | 1947 | 13857 | 10352 | 8719 |
|                1 | 2013-02-18 | 1917 | 10026 |  9848 | 8493 |
```

Edit #1, If you were to normalize the two tables you would still have to use dynamic SQL to get the column headers for each `personCategoryId`, however you would be able to remove the *unpivot* of both tables. The code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @personCategoryId int = 1

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(AntigenValue) 
                    from reftblDSAColumnLabels
                    where PersonCategoryId = @personCategoryId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT personCategoryId, SampleDate,' + @cols + '  
             from
              (
                select l.personCategoryId, d.SampleDate,
                    l.AntigenValue l_value, d.AntigenValue d_value
                from reftblDSAColumnLabels l
                inner join tblDSAData d
                  on l.PersonCategoryId = d.PersonCategoryId
                  and l.AntigenNum = d.AntigenNum
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                max(d_value)
                for l_value in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fc3f/1)

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive answer, you obviously put some time and effort into it and I'm really grateful for that.
If I were to take on-board your suggestion to normalize reftblDSAColumnLabels & tblDSAData how would that impact the dynamic query?
Would the 'select @cols...' statement still be required to provide the column names from reftblDSAColumnLabels which can then be fed into the main SELECT statement?

Comment: @Neil Yes, even you normalize the tables the column headers will be changing for each `personCategoryId` so you will have to use dynamic sql to get the result.  I added a sample query and a demo with that version -- demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fc3f/1

Comment: Many thanks again, that was really well explained. Your final query certainly looks a lot neater when the tables are normalized.